# Is there any open source task scheduling system for big data platform?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, bigdata

I want to find a open source task scheduling system which can cover below kinds of task. Such as MapReduce、Hive、Pig、Spark、Java、Shell、Python and so on.
Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Recommendation of tools is off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can schedule tasks using `crontab`. Search for it.

Comment: Are you looking at any specific features with it? Do you plan to allocate resources to each of them? Do you need Docker compatibility? Are you running on a mutli-cloud environment?
For now, I would advise to look at [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software#Job_scheduling_products_with_ERP_support) from wikipedia. Some solutions are open source but not all provide the same features.